# What is the most common vowel?

Tags: cross-linguistic, vowels, ipa

Of all the languages for which there is sufficient data, including extinct languages, which vocalic speech sound, or phone, as represented by the IPA, has been used most?

Comment: By whom? As allophone or phoneme? In which transcription system? With what phonological rules? Etc. The question is not answerable, alas.

Comment: Vowels are a continuum, so that's probably hard to answer. One way to make the question more answerable might be: Grouping vowels with respect to close/mid/open, front/mid/back and unrounded/rounded, which is the group populated by the most languages. I guess it would also depend on how exactly you distinguish a language from a dialect...

Comment: Oh, I guess you edited the question, so you're grouping them with regards to IPA transcription. Fair enough.

Comment: Except that "languages" do not "use" IPA symbols. Linguists use IPA symbols, and they use them for many different purposes, phonemic, phonetic, orthographically, educationally, etc. The question is still unanswerable, without further qualification.

Comment: Given that schwa-centering of unstressed vowels is a common phenomenon it may be the most 'common' in production, but then in those it is only a an allophone, not the underlying form.

Comment: the comments above are good to keep in mind. the answer is probably /a/. google "Simple UPSID Interface" to get some quantitative data.

Comment: @LaurenG I think schwa is the winner. I use ət məre thən əll əthər vəwəls pət təgəthər.

Comment: @bytebuster - but that's only in English - I know it's a process that happens in other languages too, just don't have the time to check how common it is cross-linguistically!

Comment: @bytebuster But that gets back to the questions jlawler raised: the schwa in your example sentence is an allophone of various other vowel phonemes, so should it count as [schwa] or as each of the phonemes (I think you had 7 different vowels represented by schwa)?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut The question is answerable, and the answer is that there is no answer. Here's the reason: **The vocalic matix is a continuous set**. Speaking mathematically, for any sounds `A` and `B`, and `A < B` there is always such `C` exists that `A < C < B`. This is true for at least three dimensions (height, backness, and roundness). If you stick to a *certain language*, you can get to *Cardinal vowels*, whose set is not continuous. The OP specifically said "of all the languages". Also, a set of graphemes is not continuous; also excluded by the OP: "vocalic sound".

Comment: @bytebuster What you say may be correct in terms of articulation and acoustics, but not in terms of perception as here we have phonetic vowel phones (a continuous set) and phonemic vowel phones (a categorial set). And cardinal vowels (as per Daniel Jones) is a phonetic notion, not tied to any particular language. Finally, for the purposes of SE, I think that no answer is not an answer.

Comment: I guess you are right about the Cardinal vowels. However, it's an interesting concept [whether or not a Q with no valid A, valid by itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149429/is-theres-no-answer-an-answer). Do you mind I have raised it @Meta?

Comment: It is true, and important to note, that vowels form a continuum and are not discrete, but what is proposed here - that there is simply *no answer* (and that there cannot be one) - seems very odd to me. Of course continuous variables can have a mean, median, variance and so on. (I understand that we need first to operationalize vowel quality in a way that makes sense, and there's many conceivable ways in which we could do that, but that doesn't change the point) I believe some people here are trying to be too dismissive of a question that has its validity, even if it needs to be more precise.

Comment: I think the average speaker of a language is aware of only a small
number of vowels in his own language, though the linguist will see a
lot more, and can even convince the speaker of that, though it makes
no difference. THis is certainly true in my language. - - - - - - Why do you people, who have a good grasp of these issues keep answering in comments, in a way that defeats the purpose of the site?

Answer (score 1):

In spoken language it is very likely the schwa [ə]. The schwa is frequent in speech due to a common form of vowel reduction, centralization. This is especially present in rapid speech where vowels may not be perfectly articulated all the time. Also, many languages that are written abjad-wise have the schwa as their most frequent vowel phoneme.

Answer (score 1):

The answer primarily hinges on the meaning of the construction "has been used by more languages, with more frequency than any other", especially whether "with more frequency than any other" adds anything to the question, i.e. whether it means "and occurs with greater token frequency than any other". Since I cannot think of any reason to interpret the clause in that way, I assume that is just another way of asking which vowel is found in more languages. The top contenders are [i] and [a], which in UPSID are a dead heat (language count i=393, a=392). Schwa on the other hand only appears in 134 languages. I would say that it is currently unknown which of *a* vs. *i* is found in more languages.

Comment: Thanks! Is the UPSID data analysis linkable?

Comment: Sort of. http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/faciliti/sales/upsid.zip has what you need, though figuring out the encoding is not totally trivial. Also look at http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid_segment_freq.html for an online list of segments and frequencies. The main problem will be merging across diacritics, i.e. nasalization, tone, stress blah blah blah aren't relevant to the question to asked, but they are all treated as separate phonemes, so you have to sum up across diacritics.

Answer (score -2):

A or/and E.

Vowels are much more of a continuum than consonants. Within each language different vowels are separated by different contrastivity, like height, backness and roundness. These contrast lines are very much dependent on how many different vowels the language is believed to use phonemically.

One way to describe these vowel sounds, is to write them in plain writing, using the appropriate alphabet. This is not the same as IPA-alphabet, but it is still the most frequent way to describe a vowel sound. It is also a way to actually making continuus vowel sounds to be discrete.

There exists several lists counting letters in languages. This Wikipedia page gives an overview: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency

The question is also difficult to answer, because you are mixing frequency of languages and frequency within languages. What counts most, people talking, percentage of usage worldwide, or percentage of usage within each language?

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question proper: the asker didn't inquire about the frequency of letters but of the frequency of phone(me)s as found in varying languages.